# Entity Framework: how to annotate two one-to-one relationships to same table

Tags: entity-framework

In a punch clock application, a given day has two foreign keys into the Punches table: PunchId_In and PunchId_Out. How can you annotate this relationship so Entity Framework creates it as intended? Note: One or both of these foreign keys may be undefined (null).

```
public class Day
{
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public int? PunchId_In { get; set; }
    public int? PunchId_Out { get; set; }
    public virtual Punch PunchIn { get; set; }
    public virtual Punch PunchOut { get; set; }
}

public class Punch
{
    public int PunchID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PunchDT { get; set; }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate which foreign key matches each navigation property.

```
public class Day
{
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public int? PunchId_In { get; set; }
    public int? PunchId_Out { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PunchId_In")]
    public virtual Punch PunchIn { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PunchId_Out ")]
    public virtual Punch PunchOut { get; set; }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the response.

When adding migration I got this error message: "The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'PunchIn' on type 'xx.xx.Day' is not valid. The property 'PunchId_In' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'xx.xx.Punch'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property."

Does that mean that the InverseProperty must be a navigation property on the Punch side?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it wasn't a collection. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  This time the migration was added but got a different error when updating database: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Days_dbo.Punches_PunchId_Out' on table 'Days' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.  I read somewhere that this needs to be done in Fluent API, for which a better name would be Arameic API :)  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have existing fluent configs? Is this a new DB or an  existing one? Take a look at the Up() code of the migration and see what it is trying to do.

Comment: Good idea. The current migration (which SLQ Server protested as I mentioned above) has the following code:                CreateTable(
                "dbo.Days",
                c => new   
                    {
   ...
                    })
  ...
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Punches", t => t.PunchId_In, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Punches", t => t.PunchId_Out, cascadeDelete: true)
  ...   I havent been able to convert that into fluent api code for the model builder that EF will accept.

Comment: Hi Steve,  My apologies. The code I synthesized to present here was slightly different than the one I was testing: PunchId_In and PunchId_Out were int and not int? as I showed above.  When I made them nullable your second suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider redesigning your model.

Based on the information that you shared: Your model assumes that you only punch in and out once each day and it does not keep track of who punched in or out.

You could just have a list of "Punches"

- ID
- Who - link to person table
- When - DateTime
- Type - (In / Out)

Then filter the list as needed

Comment: I do consider possibility of multiple in/out timespans, but didn't mention it here.  Thanks.